# Django: save a OneToOneField automatically from *related* model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider two models (ignoring the obvious logical issues):

```
class Owner(m.Model):
    id = m.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Pet(m.Model):
    owner = m.OneToOneField(Owner, related_name="pet", primary_key=True)
```

When creating a new `Owner`, is it possible to have their `.pet` saved automatically?

Currently, this is what happens:

```
>>> o = Owner()
>>> o.pet = Pet()
>>> o.save()
>>> o.id
42
>>> o.pet.id
None
>>> o.pet.owner_id
None
>>> o.pet.owner == o
True
```

But I would like (and expect?) that `o.pet` would be saved in the process of saving `o`.

Notes:

- If you're going to suggest overriding `Owner.save`: how should the situation when `commit=False` be handled?
- Moving the `OneToOneField` from `Pet` to `Owner` is undesirable, as it will result in a less sensible database schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `django.db.models.signals.post_save` to achieve the desired outcome without overriding `Owner.save()`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

post_save.connect(save_pet_handler, sender=Owner, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")

def save_pet_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Once `o.save()` is called, a signal will be fired to call `save_pet_handler`, where you can then have `o.pet` saved or updated, depends on the boolean value of `created`.